# How did Mao regain and consolidate power after the Great Famine?

Tags: china, communism, mao-zedong

Mao Zedong's position had weakened after the Great Famine, and in the period during and leading up to the Cultural Revolution, he regained and consolidated his power. I am interested in getting a better picture of the very concrete ways in which he did this during this period. What are classic books that describes these events accurately and in detail?

Comment: In most cases requests for book recommendations are off-topic here, since what makes a 'good' book is somewhat subjective (and depends heavily on the reader's own interests and knowledge).

Comment: @SteveBird, is this better?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Mao-Story-Jung-Chang/dp/0099507374

Comment: The best book to answer "How did Mao regain and consolidate power?" is ["How the Red Sun Rose"](http://cup.columbia.edu/book/how-the-red-sun-rose/9789629968229) by prof. Gaohua. I don't read the translated version so I don't know if the translation is good or not. But I highly recommend any work by Prof. [Gaohua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_the_Red_Sun_Rose) but this book seem to be the only translated version available.

Comment: I believe that, in theory, its possible to ask if there's a canonical work on a subject. I say "in theory" because I can't recall anyone doing this successfully.

Comment: @T.E.D. book recommendation is a question I always want to ask but don't know where to ask.

Comment: We have at some points experimented with a [list question format](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2081/proposal-for-accepting-reference-list-requests), but the scheme there really only works if there's likely to be a decent-sized list.